# SUM Excel column if row not blank, otherwise take value from left cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum

I have a table:

```
Job name        Cost    Assessment
----------------------------------
Job 1            400    200
Job 2            100    30
Job 3            80     
Job 4            100    10
Job 5            20    
Job 6            340        
----------------------------------
SUM              1040   680
```

I need some formula, that SUM Assessment column, but if cell is empty, take value from left cell.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming columns are A, B, and C, and by "if cell is empty, take value from left cell" you mean if column C is empty, take value from column B, then you have 2 options:

1) Add in an additional column (D) with the following formula:

```
=if(C3="",B3,C3)
```

You can then sum column D.

2) Use the following formula in the sum range:

```
=SUM(C3:C8)+SUMIFS(B3:B8,C3:C8,"")
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. The tags are for excel, so the formulae work in excel.

Comment: oh, sorry. My fault.

Comment: The second formula works in Google Spreadsheets, maybe there's an issue with the row reference, since they start at row 3 in the example?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach my problem was with argument separator. I've used commas instead of semicolon. FP.